# Why start() is not working in my extension of Thread

Tags: java, runnable

I am getting output when i called `run()` through `t.start()`, but not getting same output through `obj.start()`. what may be the reason?

Can anyone explain this?

```
class Ex1 implements Runnable {

    int n;
    String s;

    public void run(){
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            System.out.println( s +"-->"+ i);
        }
    }   
}


class RunnableDemo extends Thread {

    Ex1 e;
    RunnableDemo(Ex1 e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Ex1 obj1 = new Ex1();
        Ex1 obj2 = new Ex1();

        obj1.n = 5;
        obj1.s = "abc";

        // Thread t = new Thread(obj1);
        // t.start();
        RunnableDemo obj = new RunnableDemo(obj1);
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you need to call `super` in your RunnableDemo's constructor:

```
RunnableDemo(Ex1 e){
        super(obj);
        this.e = e;
}
```

This calls the super class's (`Thread`) constructor with the obj argument, so that the start method works as expected.

Without doing this, you are actually implictly calling super with no arguments, thus no runnable is set for the RunnableDemo instance.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `@Override` to `run()`:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        System.out.println( s +"-->"+ i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't override the `run` method when making a subclass of `Thread`. Since the default `run` method does not do anything, you won't get any result.